# How do I undo an apache2 ubuntu HTTP HTTPS redirect?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-http-server, ssl, redirection

I've got an apache2 instance running, with HTTPS redirect running:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin support@myco.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www"
    ServerName www.myco.com
    ServerAlias myco.com

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin support@myco.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    ServerName www.myco.com
    ServerAlias myco.com

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
...
```

Works fine.
I decided I needed to enable the non-encrypted vHost on the httpd in order to speed up some internal transfers, but I removed the Rewrite lines in the config, made the DocRoot specific to /var/www/other, and added some normal HTTP directives, such copies of the Directrory-related directives from the above HTTPS config (but different paths).

When I do `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`
it restarts OK, no errors in the log, but the site still redirects in my cache-emptied browser.

I still need the SSL-site to operate normally, but what if I wanted different content when I hit the site on port 80?

Comment: Could you use [Name-based Virtual Hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html), and just expose the non-SSL option on specific host-names?